# Enemies movement is not smooth

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When my enemies move, they move from one position to the next without moving in between the points. I want the enemies to move between two positions smoothly, and I do not understand why the enemies do not do so with the following code.

```
public class UltPatrol : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public Transform Enemypos;
    private float waitTime;
    public float StartwaitTime;
    public float MinX;
    public float MaxX;
    public float MinY;
    public float MaxY;
    private void Start()
    {
        Enemypos = GetComponentInParent<Transform>();
        waitTime = StartwaitTime;
        Enemypos.localPosition = new Vector2(Random.Range(MinX, MaxX), Random.Range(MinY, MaxY));
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        transform.localPosition = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.localPosition, Enemypos.localPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.localPosition, Enemypos.localPosition) <0.2f)
        {
            if (waitTime <= 0)
            {
                Enemypos.localPosition = new Vector2(Random.Range(MinX, MaxX), Random.Range(MinY, MaxY));
                waitTime = StartwaitTime;
            }
            else
            {
                waitTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `speed`?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to get your game to look like this[image]

All I did was remove the line

```
Enemypos = GetComponentInParent<Transform>();
```

And then in the editor, I un-parented the two objects, and assigned the value of Enemypos in the inspector.

Comment: yes, i want the enemies to move like that, but unable to replicate what you did successfully.

Comment: You did all of the things that I did? You deleted that one line of code, un-parented the two objects, and then assigned the value of Enemypos in the inspector?